# How to handle floating point exceptions (fpe) with Rust?

Tags: rust

In C you can use `SIGFPE` to define a handler for floating point exceptions.

How would you use Rust to define a function that handles overflow, for example?

See [this function](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/creator/creator_signals.c;3b467b35a85153e9435a1fbcba2e9c1770c1192a$305-326) for an example that sets up a callback to run in C.

Comment: What kind of action do you want to take on overflow etc., and can you point to an example of that in C?

Answer (score 3):

Rust does not support signals as part of the standard library. I believe this is because they are highly platform-specific and pretty terribly designed for most multithreaded programs.

There are a handful of crates available to deal with signals; [chan-signal](https://crates.io/crates/chan-signal) is the one I've used before. Here is the example code from that library, changed to report a `SIGFPE`:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate chan;
extern crate chan_signal;

use chan_signal::Signal;
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let signal = chan_signal::notify(&[Signal::FPE]);
    let (sdone, rdone) = chan::sync(0);

    thread::spawn(move || run(sdone));

    chan_select! {
        signal.recv() -> signal => {
            println!("received signal: {:?}", signal)
        },
        rdone.recv() => {
            println!("Program completed normally.");
        }
    }
}

fn run(_sdone: chan::Sender<()>) {
    thread::sleep_ms(100_000);
}
```

On macOS, running this in one window and `kill -s FPE $THE_RUNNING_PID` in another generates the output

```
received signal: Some(FPE)
```