# How to panic when a NaN is created?

Tags: rust, nan

I'm trying to find where a `NaN` is created in a huge codebase.  Is there some compiler flag or something I can use to panic on `NaN` so I can find what line it's on?

Comment: Pretty sure the answer is "there is nothing". I'd review where you have floating point division and make sure you aren't dividing zero by zero.

Comment: `31 results in 12 files` is what I get for searching for `/`.  There's got to be an easier way than checking each manually.

Comment: I don't think there is a platform-independent solution. You need to figure out how to enable floating-point exceptions on your platform, and then you can add a signal handler [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40857359/how-to-handle-floating-point-exceptions-fpe-with-rust).

Comment: You could take a look at the various implementations for `fegetenv` and `fesetenv` of musl libc (they're all written in assembly) for your target architecture and reimplement those in order to enable the desired traps; if those are available for your architecture.

Comment: Running GDB on a debug-build is probably the best way to do that. [It can break on floating point exceptions, including when NaN is created](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/debug.html?highlight=floating#handling-floating-point-exceptions)

Comment: @user2722968 Isn't that only for shaders?

Comment: Why would it be only for shaders? Don't confuse "GSL" (GNU Scientific Library) and "GLSL" (GL Shading Language).

Comment: @Shepmaster I found it, it was from dividing `Inf` by `Inf`, which was created by using `.exp()` on too large an `f32`.  I solved it with `as f64`.

Answer (score 2):

There's no compiler flag. The best you can do is to wrap your floats in [noisy_float](https://lib.rs/noisy_float) newtype.